# How to use variables from select inside where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm getting the halfway-point between two dates into a variable and I want to check if the halfway-point is today. I can select what I need without a problem but once I put the variables into the `WHERE` clause it seems to not work.

I tried outputting both dates I need and they are the same but when I compare them in the `WHERE` clause I don't get any results.

This shows me the columns and middle_date and todays_date are the same in one column

```
SELECT @order_date := order_date, @delivery_date := delivery_date,
ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(@order_date, ((DATEDIFF(@delivery_date, @order_date)/2)))),0) AS middle_date, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) AS todays_date FROM `order`
```

[image]

Now when I do this I don't get any results:

```
SELECT @order_date := order_date, @delivery_date := delivery_date,
ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(@order_date, ((DATEDIFF(@delivery_date, @order_date)/2)))),0) AS middle_date, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) AS todays_date FROM `order`
WHERE ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(@order_date, ((DATEDIFF(@delivery_date, @order_date)/2)))),0) = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()))
```

[image]

I expect the query to return the row where the todays_date and middle_date are same.

Comment: Post sample data and expected output (that might help)

Comment: @Kris.Kodira . . . Please provide the *base* data along with a description of the logic you want and the desired result set.  Obviously, variables are not going to work for this, the way you are using them, but it is very hard to disentangle your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without variables and without unix_timestamp

```
SELECT order_date, delivery_date,
   ADDDATE(order_date, ((DATEDIFF(delivery_date, order_date)/2))) AS middle_date, 
   DATE(NOW()) AS todays_date 
FROM `order`
WHERE ADDDATE(order_date, ((DATEDIFF(delivery_date, order_date)/2))) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: @Kris.Kodira Just a little side note: If your data is large, or when it grows, it would probably be a good idea to add something like `DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN order_date AND delivery_date`. Using only ADDDATE would necessitate a full table scan, but adding the condition I suggested would reduce the set of records whose middle_date needs calculated. _(This suggestion assumes there is an index on order_date and/or delivery_date.)_ If your data is such that order_date must always be before or on the current date, the added condition can just be `delivery_date >= DATE(NOW())`.

Comment: @Uueerdo yeah definetly. I didn't think of that at all. Since a lot of `middle_date`s don't even need to be checked. Thanks!